# Don't have permission to open/view a file on a Nativescript App

Tags: javascript, ios, nativescript

Does anyone have any idea about the following error ? I am getting this error  on latest version of iOS. Everything was working fine before now I can not import any file in my NS app.
Thanks

**CONSOLE LOG file: app/app.js:307:0: errorIOS Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=257 "The file \M-b\M^@\M^\file_Check.mcdc\M-b\M^@\M^] couldn\M-b\M^@\M^Yt be opened because you don\M-b\M^@\M^Yt have permission to view it." UserInfo={NSFilePath=/private/var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/comappleCloudDocs/Downloads/file_Check.mcdc, NSUnderlyingError=0x2819a5740 {Error Domain=N**

In App Delegate:

```
var errorIOS = new interop.Reference();
var content = NSString.alloc().initWithContentsOfURLEncodingError(url, NSUTF8StringEncoding, errorIOS);
console.log("content", content);
console.log("errorIOS", errorIOS);
console.log("errorIOS", errorIOS.value);
```

previously I had the following code but app was crashing

```
if ( application.ios ) {
var DOCDelegate = (function (_super) {
__extends(DOCDelegate, _super);
function DOCDelegate() {
_super.apply(this, arguments);
}
DOCDelegate.prototype.applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions = function (application, launchOptions) {
console.log("applicationWillFinishLaunchingWithOptions: " + launchOptions);
return true;
};
DOCDelegate.prototype.applicationDidBecomeActive = function (application) {
console.log("applicationDidBecomeActive: " + application);
};
DOCDelegate.prototype.applicationOpenURLOptions = function (application, url, options) {
console.log("applicationOpenURLOptions: " + url);
if ( applicationSettings.getBoolean("isAccessedUser", false) ){
if ( url.pathExtension === "mcdoc" ) {
try {
//var content = NSString.alloc().initWithContentsOfFile(url);
var errorIOS = NSError.new();
var content = NSString.alloc().initWithContentsOfURLEncodingError(url, NSUTF8StringEncoding, errorIOS);
if ( content !== null ) {
var json = getJsonFromContent( content );
if ( json ) {
var clName = json.Checklist.$.name;
importChecklist( clName, json );
}
}
else {
console.log("iOS Import Content Null Error");
dialogs.alert({
title: "Import Fehler",
message: "Beim Lesen der Datei ist ein Fehler aufgetreten.",
okButtonText: "OK"
});
}
} catch (error) {
console.log("iOS Import Error: " + error);
dialogs.alert({
title: "Import Fehler",
message: "Beim Lesen der Datei ist ein Fehler aufgetreten.",
okButtonText: "OK"
```

Now App does not crash but getting that error message while trying to import a file in my NSApp.

Comment: Generally importing should copy the file into your temp directory, simply using `File.fromPath(url.path)` would work.

Comment: @Manoj ` cl2Import.forEach( cl => {

            // Get file
            var file = fs.File.fromPath(cl.path);
            // Parse file
            var json = getJsonFromFile(file);
            // Get name of checklist from the parsed file
            cl.nameCL = json.Checklist.$.name`

Comment: @Manoj  my app was crashing  for this **var errorIOS = NSError.new();** then when I changed to **var errorIOS = new interop.Reference(); ** Now I got error regarding permission but app is not crashing. I have checked my import file everything lokks ok :(